How are effect sizes typically defined under complex sampling?
In some fields it is common to quote comparisons in terms of standardised effect sizes. For example, a difference in means gets scaled by the sample standard deviation to give an effect size.
This then leads to computational formulas to extract the standard deviation from other input, for example, the $t$-statistic multiplied by the square root of its degrees of freedom is approximately the scaled difference in means.  These computational formulas aren't valid under complex sampling: the relationship between the standard error of the mean and the standard deviation are more complicated. Even the simple definition as difference in means divided by standard deviation raises the question of which standard deviation -- an estimated population one?
So, the question: are there standard, widely-used formulas for standardised effect sizes that account for complex sampling?
[I'm not really interested in whether standardised effect sizes are Good or Evil, or even in suggestions for how they might best be computed under complex sampling -- I'm trying to find out about existing standards]
